# Dumping entries of a table index

Tags: database, esent, edb

I am trying to seek within the primary index of a table on a customers EDB database. And I fail miserably. I retrieved the index info using **JetGetIndexInfo** and know all about the index (it's the primary index and I know the column that's used). Now I want to seek on that index for known and existing values in order to maximize the performance, but **JetSeek** claims that it can't find the key I want to search for.

Now I am looking for a way to dump the index keys. That way I could see if I should add something to the key I am using or convert it somehow (I am absolutely sure it's the right key). Or is there another trick to find what's going wrong?

One detail that might be the reason for my failure could be the entry in **KeyFldIDs** column in the **MSysObjects** table. The particular index has some entry there. If I create an index myself that field is usually blank. What does it do?

UPDATE
@Laurion: I've managed to run dbutil on the database. Here's the extract which is relevant:

```
AdditionalData
AttId
    Coltyp:     Binary
    Columnid:   2.147.483.777
    Max length: 8
    Grbit:      None
MsgFolderIndex6
    Grbit:          IndexUnique, IndexPrimary
    CultureInfo:    en-US
    CompareOptions: IgnoreCase, IgnoreKanaType, IgnoreWidth
        AttId
            Coltyp:      Binary
            IsAscending: True
            IsASCII:     False
```

Comment: Two questions:
1. What does JetGetIndexInfo say the key columns are?
2. How are you calling JetMakeKey and JetSeek?

Comment: 1. There's only one key column. It's a primary index. 2. I simply call JetSetCurrentIndex2 with JET_bitMoveFirst, then JetMakeKey with a known and existing key (which I got from the table dump) and JET_bitNewKey, then finally JetSeek with JET_bitSeekGE.

Comment: One more thing that might be important is that the column is of type JET_coltypBinary. I read the entry from another table and seek within the index of another table to retrieve soe additional information. However I don't alter the KeyValue at any time.

Comment: Another thing I just found is that columnidcKey of the JET_INDEXLIST is 0. Does this mean that allthough the index exists it contains no key values? If true, how can this be possible? I can definitely see that the records in the table are sorted based on the particular index (or the column).

Comment: Now I'm confused. Regarding my previous comment, I get also 0 for columnidcKey and columnidcEntry when calling JetGetIndexInfo on a table I created myself and know that it contains several hundreds of records and JetSeek works fine.

Comment: Can you grab the 'ManagedEsent' project from http://managedesent.codeplex.com and build it. One of the executables is produces is DbUtil.exe, which can dump the meta-data of a database. Run 'DbUtil dumpmetadata [database]' and post the output. That will let us know exactly what the meta-data is.

Comment: Is there some information on how I can build the project?

Comment: Just open the solution and build everything. I believe the free version of Visual Studio should be able to do that if you don't currently have a copy.

Comment: Which file is the solution? In the zip there are esedb.py, esedbshelve.py, Esent.Collections.dll, Esent.Collections.pdb, Esent.Collections.XML, Esent.Interop.dll, Esent.Interop.pdb, Esent.Interop.xml and README.rtf. Visual Studio doesn't help me on this.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I managed to download the proper files and so the build. I'll come back with the results when I manage to set the pagesize properly.

Comment: @Laurion. Okay, it's done. I've extracted the metadata, see above at my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that index, this sequence of calls should work:

```
JetOpenTable(...)
JetMakeKey(sesid, tableid, pvData, cbData, JET_bitNewKey);
JetSeek(sesid, tableid, JET_bitSeekEQ);
```

If you want to dump the index keys you could do this:

```
JetOpenTable(...);
Use JetGetTableColumnInfo to get the ID of the column called "AttId"
Use JetMove to walk the table sequentially, retrieving and dumping the column values
```

The most likely error is that you are passing in an incorrect cbData value when making the key, possibly an off-by-one error, or sizeof() problem.

Comment: Thanks alot! I looked into it again and you were right about cbData. There was one Byte missing!